# Error exporting .geojson

Tags: qgis, geojson, export, error

Error exporting .geojson file with polygon, line and point data. Attached is the screenshot of the error for reference. Can anyone suggest solution for this kind of error [image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried export without the field causing the failure?

Comment: @Erik there is no such a field in the data

Comment: If your `.json` actually contains two or more different geometry types, you can't export it to `.shp` without prior separation of geometries.

Comment: @Erick they are already separated. I have single .json with separate point, line and polygon data in it

Comment: And the error happens with all three geojson files?

Comment: It's a bit confusing: you say you have separated the data, but otherwise you state: "file with polygon, line and point data." Can you provide more details and a screenshot? How does your attribute table looks like?

Comment: @Erik yes it happens with all three

Comment: @Babel Please find added screenshot

Comment: Can you provide example data? Have you made sure thre's no incompatibilty with characters in the attribute table and the unicode you are using?

Comment: Try renaming your fieldnames via "refactor fields" from processing toolbox, then export your layers.

Comment: Please remember to always include error messages as text in the body of the question. Images are not legible on all devices and cannot be searched by others with a similar problem.

Comment: I can't think why exporting a layer to a GeoJSON file would throw an error relating to Shapefile DBF components. Or are you exporting what was a GeoJSON file to a Shapefile? Please be clear and detail the menu options you are clicking on.

Comment: @Erick You are right the mistake is in attribute names. It is cleared now and my data is exporting